# How to sort primefaces lazy data table on calculated fields

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, jsf-2, lazy-loading

I have an entity Foo and ABC.

```
 @Entity
 public class Foo{

        @Id
        @Column
        private int id;

        @Column
        private Double amount;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ABC_ID")
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private ABC abc;

        //calculated dervived field which needs to be called in primefaces
        private totalAmount;
    }
```

Now mathematically `totalAmount` is calculated below:

```
totalAMOunt = amount + (amount*abc.rate)
```

How can i do this in Hiberate mapping? can i map this second table column and use `@Formula`?

it will be called in primefaces

```
<p:column sortBy=#{"foo.totalAmount"} />
```

Please help.